# how to escape or href in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, escaping

One of the field in my database contains data with some `html` tags say `img`, `href`. While querying I want to ignore those tags. If a tag contains `href="foo.com"` then my search query for foo in mysql should not brings the `foo.com`. It should ignore links, image links etc.

Comment: Where is your table schema? Where is your attempt at solving this?

Comment: @Shef; Right Now I am using beautiful soup to escape the html tag from the content and then  save those data in the database. But I want to save those content as it is in the database and escape the data those tags at database level. The field which content I need to escape is of longtext Type.

Comment: If you don't give us some sample data, and what you want out of it and what not, then we just can't make a guess.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, MySQL does not have any sort of built-in HTML parser and I doubt there's a simple way to write one.

My advice is to add a new column to the table with a plain text version of your HTML column and use it to perform searches. Whatever your server-side language is, it's likely to have a library to strip HTML tags. For instance, PHP has [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags).